# Activity diagram for android application

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I've started creating the activity diagram of my android application but I'm not sure if I made it correctly. It is not finished but I want to know if I am on a correct path. Can somebody check it for me please?
[image: Activity diagram]

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid :

- you surely do not do in parallel *view post list* etc and *create post*, so the *fork* is wrong
- in case you have a *fork* its branches must be merged using a *join* but you use a *merge*
- it is the same after to do *search* or *share post* etc

Probably you show menus / buttons and the user select an entry / push a button isn't it ? for that use a *decision node* with the right guards to say what was chosen, note you are not limited to only 2 outgoing flows from a *decision node*

Comment: @KjfdnskdjgnSdjfskjdn also what about to use a UML tool to draw your activity rather than (it seems) to use a general drawing tool ?